# How to parse CSV file skipping lines with odd number of attributes as one-liner?

Tags: scala, csv

I'd like to solicit feedback (aka code review) on the following method that parses a CSV file skipping lines with odd number of attributes -- the 2nd line in the CSV file below:

```
e,2,3,13,k1,v1,k2,v2
e,2,2,10,k1,v1,k2  // this line should be skipped
```

I'm concerned that I have to use `Option` to skip incorrect lines. I'm thinking of using `foldLeft` instead. Is there a better approach?

```
def getEdges(seq: Seq[Seq[String]]): Seq[Edge] =
  seq.filter(_.head == "e").map { case Seq("e", i, s, t, attrs @ _*) =>
    if (attrs.size % 2 != 0) {
      println(s"Incorrect edge - odd number of attributes [${attrs.size}] for id=[${attrs.size}}]...skipping")
      None
    } else {
      val attrsM = attrs.grouped(2).toList.map(l => l.head -> l.tail.head).toMap + ("guid" -> i)
      Some(Edge(i, s, t, attrsM))
    }
  }.filterNot(_ == None).map(_.get)
```

Comment: Why not `seq.filter(_.size % 2 == 1)`  ?

Comment: You have 4 main attributes, then if you no need printed info about dropped lines you can check length of entire Seq inside first filter. Then you no need to use Option because each line after filter will match your expectations. 
If you need this info line you can just change `.filterNot(_ == None).map(_.get)` into `.flatMap(o => o) `

Answer (score 2):

`collect` is made for exactly this sort of thing.

```
// Note--we don't need filter any more as it's part of the condition
seq.collect {
  case Seq("e", i, s, t, attrs @ _*) if checksize(attrs) =>
    val attrsM = ...
    Edge(...)
}
```

And then something like

```
def checksize(size: Int) = {
  if (size % 2 == 0) true
  else {
    println("Tsk tsk.")
    false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you no need informations about dropped lines you can use this code:

```
def getEdges(seq: Seq[Seq[String]]): Seq[Edge] =
  seq.filter(sub => (sub.head == "e") && (sub.length % 2 == 0)).map {
    case Seq("e", i, s, t, attrs @ _*) =>
      val attrsM = attrs.grouped(2).collect { case List(k, v) => k -> v}.toMap + ("guid" -> i)
      Edge(i, s, t, attrsM)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

flatMap will automatically remove your None:

```
List(Some(1), None).flatMap(x => x) == List(1)
```

That might make it simpler.

**EDIT**

By discussing matter in comments it seems that best way is to avoid Option and by using combo of `filter` and `map` or the `collect` function that does both in one pass.

Sample code:

```
List(List(1,2,3),List(1,2,3,4),List(2,3,4)).collect{ case arg @ List(1, rest @ _*) if(rest.length%2==0) => arg.sum }
```

Comment: Thanks! Still I'll have to use `Option` to mark what should be removed from the collection. I'd rather avoid wrapping the elements into a `Option`.

Comment: Then foldLeft is the way to go. You just pass the accumulator without appending to it.

Comment: You can also checkout collect function, it takes partial function and skips those that are not defined:

 `List(List(1,2,3),List(2,3,4,5)).collect{ case arg @ List(1, rest @ _*) if(rest.length%2==0) => arg.sum }`

Comment: foldLeft is a ridiculously expensive way to build up a collection (new immutable object at every step, instead of making use of internal collections mutability in filter). Use lions-share to watch the churn turn your heap into cheese.

Comment: That is not completly true. Lists in scala when you prepend does not build up a new collection. Just sets the pointer.

`B->C->D` here actually you can tell that you have 3 or even 4 lists. Of course at the end of foldLeft you need to reverse your list but that scala internally does with mutable builders.

Comment: What @almendar says is true. But I wouldn't bother with `Option` in this case. Just filter for wrong lines and then feed each of them into `Edge` constructor using `map`. Pseudo code could look like this: `seq.filter(_.size % 2 == 1 ).map(Edge)`. It can't get any easier.

Comment: That's exactly what collect does. Filter and map in one call so those are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `for` comprehension:

```
def getEdges(seq: Seq[Seq[String]]): Seq[Edge] =
    for {
      Seq("e", i, s, t, attrs@_ *) <- seq if attrs.length % 2 == 0
      attrsM = attrs.grouped(2).map { case Seq(a, b) => a -> b}.toMap + ("guid" -> i)
    } yield Edge(i, s, t, attrsM)
```

if you want to print invalid lines (not a one-liner any more, but I think still reads quite nicely):

```
def validLine(cols:Seq[String]) = if (cols.length % 2 == 0) true else {
  println(s"Line $cols is invalid")
  false
}
def getEdges(seq: Seq[Seq[String]]): Seq[Edge] =
  for {
    Seq("e", i, s, t, attrs@_ *) <- seq if attrs.length % 2 == 0
    attrsM = attrs.grouped(2).map { case Seq(a, b) => a -> b}.toMap + ("guid" -> i)
  } yield Edge(i, s, t, attrsM)
```